# Counting the same rows of 2D matrix

Tags: matlab, octave, accumarray

I have a two column matrix. I need to make it three column, where the third column shows the number of appearance of the first two as a row in the input matrix.

Basically: **Input**

```
[1 1;
 1 1;
 1 2;
 1 2;
 1 3]
```

**Desired output:**

```
[1 1 2;
 1 2 2;
 1 3 1]
```

I know already that a proper combination of accumarray and unique should do the charm. I just don't know how to properly combine them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, [`unique`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and [`accumarray`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) are perfectly suited for this task:

```
x = [1 1; 1 1; 1 2; 1 2; 1 3]; % input
[~, v, w] = unique(x, 'rows', 'stable'); % unique indices and labels
c = accumarray(w, 1); % counts
y = [x(v,:) c]; % output
```

Remove the `'stable'` flag if you want the ouput rows sorted in lexicographical order.

You can also replace `accumarray` by [`bsxfun`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to obtain the counts:

```
c = sum(bsxfun(@eq, unique(w), w.'), 2);
```

---

For the special case that the entries of `x` are positive integers and you want the ouput in lexicographical order, you can also use [`sparse`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) and [`find`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) as follows:

```
x = [1 1; 1 1; 1 2; 1 2; 1 3]; % input
[ii,jj,vv] = find(sparse(x(:,1), x(:,2), 1));
y = [ii(:), jj(:), vv(:)]; % output
```

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution:

```
clear
a=...
[1 1;
 1 1;
 1 2;
 1 2;
 1 3]

[U,~,ic]=unique(a,'rows');
[C] = histc(ic,unique(ic));
Result=[U,C]
```

Comment: Pity that `histc` is being deprecated. With the new `hitstcounts` you would need to append `inf` and transpose to achieve the same: `C = histcounts(ic,[unique(ic); inf]).'`